# Switch content, animation its contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm developing a landing page using a contentSwitcher, everything is working fine, but I;m wondering how to animate its contents one after another, just to add some fancy style. [Test Landing Page](http://jsfiddle.net/n29YG/)

You may see there are a title, subtitle, a paragraph and images below, How can I add fadeIn to each of those elements Separated by some seconds of each other?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback functions that will be triggered when an animation is complete

Take a look here:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Example:

```
$('#element1').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // this will be called then the first animation is complete

        $('#element2').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // this will be called then the second animation is complete

            $('#element3').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            // this will be called then the third animation is complete


            });


        });

});
```

To delay the animations for some seconds, use .delay()

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Thank you sotn0r, I resolve to add your suggestions, updated: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/n29YG/11/)

Comment: I'm stuck again, I have 2 containers (id), each container has it's own menu. I wish to switch between those containers, because each of those represent a different language content. I assigned the toggle call, but after switching, the first script stop working. What is the best way to get this? What I'm doing wrong?. Please help! [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/n29YG/12/)